# Значения в скобках у класса

Tags: python

Только начал изучать Python и столкнулся с конструкцией типа:

```
class ModelName(str, Enum):
    alexnet = "alexnet"
    resnet = "resnet"
    lenet = "lenet"
```

Знаю, что в скобках обычно указывается класс, от которого мы наследуемся, но что в данном случае значат эти два выражения в рамках этого класса?

Comment: почитайте про миксины в питоне

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Класс `ModelName` наследует от двух других классов(`str, Enum`). То есть объектам класса `ModelName` будут доступны все атрибуты и методы наследуемых классов, помимо собственных.
Вы можете убедится в этом, используя точечное обращение к объекту после его инициализации:

```
my_object = ModelName()
my_object.
```

Или `print(dir(my_object))` - выведет список всех атрибутов и методов объекта.

Answer (score 1):

Это означает то, что класс наследовал у. `str` и `Enum` и имеет их же атрибуты. Тем самым, мы можем воспользоваться одним из их атрибутов:

```
from enum import Enum
from typing import SupportsIndex


class ModelName(str, Enum):
    alexnet = "alexnet"
    resnet = "resnet"
    lenet = "lenet"

    def split(self, sep: str | None = ..., maxsplit: SupportsIndex = ...) -> list[str]:
        pass
```

Comment: Фактически то же самое, что и в соседнем ответе. В чем магический смысл переопределения метода split пустым методом - не понятно (при том что вы пишите про использование методов, а не их переопределение).